# How can i make the "after edit result" in Spring, Ajax, Jquery to be on top (first)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I've been making CRUD and it's finished. But the problem is after i've done edit, it's just that inconvinient for the users if they had to scroll waaayy down to search for his data to check after his edit if he's input the right data or not.
So i wanted it to be on top after editing.

Anyone have any idea how to?

Answer (score 0):

Sort your table on modifiedDate, and once crud operation finish, rebind/reload your page. This will ensure that entry last edited always remains on the top.